# Console Buffer issues on changing console size(WinAPI)

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to change console size with WinApi, i have succeded changing the size of the window etc but when i print to the console i dont get all information printed in the console window and i cant understand why this is happening? When i remove the resizing code everything works fine. I think the issue is related to that the size of the console buffer is to small.
SetConsoleSize(int, int) is called first in main.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <windows.h>

static void SetConsoleSize(int x, int y) {
 HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
 SetConsoleTitle("Title!");

 COORD coordinates;
 coordinates.X = x;
 coordinates.Y = y;

 SMALL_RECT windowRect;
 windowRect.Top = 0;
 windowRect.Left = 0;
 windowRect.Bottom = x - 1;
 windowRect.Right = y - 1;

 // Adjust buffer size:
 HANDLE handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
 if (!SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(handle, coordinates))
     throw std::runtime_error("Unable to resize screen buffer.");

 // display as a maximized window
 ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_MAXIMIZE);
}
```

Comment: It's hard to know from your description exactly what your problem is. Maybe add a screenshot showing what you see and what you are expecting instead.

Answer (score 0):

Information in window was overwriten since the buffer for console window was two small, see COORD coordinates  which decide the size of the console window buffer.

Solution code below, observe that different screen sizes can cause issue since there is no code for eval screen size only origin {0,0} as start position:

```
static void SetConsoleSize() {
 HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
 SetConsoleTitle("Title);

 CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO sbInfo;
 GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdOut, &sbInfo);

 COORD coordinates;
 coordinates.X = 80; // size of line.
 coordinates.Y = 1000; //Number of lines.

 SMALL_RECT windowRect;
 windowRect.Top = 0;
 windowRect.Left = 0;
 windowRect.Bottom = 40;
 windowRect.Right = 79;

 //set textbuffer size
 assert(SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hStdOut, coordinates));

 //change window size.
 assert(SetConsoleWindowInfo(hStdOut, true, &windowRect));

 const HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();

 SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE); //Positioning the    window
}
```